# Black screen after waking from suspend Ubuntu Budgie 18.10

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

I have a Dell XPS 15 9570 with Ubuntu Budgie 18.10 installed on it. When I'm using the integrated graphics card from Intel (by issuing `sudo prime-select intel`) everything works smoothly, but when I select the NVIDIA dedicated graphics card (issuing `sudo prime-select nvidia`) I can't wake from suspend: when I re-open the lid after having closed it, the screen remains black. I can tell that the system actually woke up because the fan makes some noise and the keyboard's backlight works fine.

My dedicated graphics card is the Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, and the driver version is 390.87

How to fix this?

Comment: This isn't a general tech helpdesk, see the [help].

Comment: Wrong site, I'm afraid. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to update your driver, here check this:

https://github.com/JackHack96/dell-xps-9570-ubuntu-respin/issues/81

also, I suggest you join this repo, it's been very useful to me ever since I've got my hands on this machine.

Comment: Yeah, I eventually solved the problem thanks to that tutorial, but I had to install KDE Neon because Ubuntu budgie would not work even with the latest drivers

Comment: @FrancescoCariaggi did you change the powermizer settings to adaptive?